# flipclock.js in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, flipclock

I want a timer on my website like this one: [flipClock.js](http://flipclockjs.com/).
I downloaded the code and tested the base.html file. Everything worked fine.

Now I copied the code and included the css and js files in my codeigniter project like this:

```
<head>
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><div class="clock" style="margin:2em;"></div>
            <div class="message">
            </div>

    </div>
</body>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clock;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var clock;

        clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
            clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
            autoStart: false,
            callbacks: {
                stop: function() {
                   $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
                }
            }
        });

        clock.setTime(220880);
        clock.setCountdown(true);
        clock.start();

    });
</script>
```

Now, when I load my webpage, no timer shows up. In the console I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).FlipClock is not a function"

Please can someone help me?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400090/flipclock-js-shooting-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-flipclock-o#answers) solution works for you.

Comment: check first your js file link is working

Answer (score 0):

This is working :

```js
var clock;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var clock;

  clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    autoStart: false,
    callbacks: {
      stop: function() {
        $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
      }
    }
  });

  clock.setTime(220880);
  clock.setCountdown(true);
  clock.start();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/master/src/flipclock/css/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/master/compiled/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call the JS Library

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And your code `<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/flipclock.min.js"></script>`

So you should place `flipclock.min.js` should place outside of application folder.

```
application
Js
   flipclock.min.js
Index.php
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).FlipClock is not a function

I got a similar error message when I used the following:

```
var clock = $('.myTime-Clock').FlipClock({ // ... your options here });
```

Finally the following worked:

```
var clock = new FlipClock($('.myTime-Clock'), {  });
```

Ref: http://flipclockjs.com/#basic-example